# Edit Image properties WYSIWYG Editor Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to change the menu of WYSIWYG editor on my Drupal 7 site. I have seen these window:

[image: image propierties]

The problem is that I have checked the CKEditor configuration and the IMCE configuration and I don't see nothing to change this.

I would like to add some propierties, spaces or borders in my pop up.

Right now I have this:

[image: now]

My drupal version is 7.4

Comment: If you're drupal version is really 7.4 (instead of 7.43), stop what you're doing and upgrade. That version contains a major remote security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor is a complex module to incorporate into your Drupal site, and takes a bit of tinkering to get just right. The way that I like to use CKEditor, and the way that I think is best, is to incorporate CKEditor with the newest version of Media (7.x-2.0-beta1) https://www.drupal.org/project/media, but that is going slightly off-topic...

You really do not even need the IMCE module because CKEditor has the plugin in module, if you select the correct package from the CKEditor site http://ckeditor.com/download. Be sure to select, 'Full Package' before downloading CKEditor from their website, and then once this is downloaded, you'll want to add all of these files into the CKEditor module (sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor). This directory in the module should be empty, at least, until you incorporate the download from the CKEditor website.

I hope this helps! If you would like assistance with incorporating into the Media module (makes Drupal function like WordPress's image/file library), let me know.